# Pandas - extract date from datetime and plus one day if the time passes a certain hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say I have this dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Date": ["2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06"],  
        "Time_End":["2018-08-05 13:50:00", "2018-08-05 14:26:00", "2018-08-05 17:30:00", "2018-08-05 17:10:00", "2018-08-06 11:23:00"],
        "Reason":["blah1", "blah2", "blah3", "blah4", "blah5"]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df

        Date             Time_End          Reason
0   2018-08-05      2018-08-05 13:50:00     blah1
1   2018-08-05      2018-08-05 14:26:00     blah2
2   2018-08-05      2018-08-05 17:30:00     blah3
3   2018-08-05      2018-08-05 17:10:00     blah4
4   2018-08-06      2018-08-06 11:23:00     blah5
```

I want to extract only the date from "Time_End" to a new column called "Birth_date". However, I would also like to check if the time passes 17:00 or not. If it does, the date extracted will be plus one to become the following day. Below show the desired output.

```
    Date        Birth_date      Time_End            Reason
0   2018-08-05  2018-08-05  2018-08-05 13:50:00     blah1
1   2018-08-05  2018-08-05  2018-08-05 14:26:00     blah2
2   2018-08-05  2018-08-06  2018-08-05 17:30:00     blah3
3   2018-08-05  2018-08-06  2018-08-05 17:10:00     blah4
4   2018-08-06  2018-08-06  2018-08-06 11:23:00     blah5
```

I came up with this but it doesn't work in the way I expected.

```
df["after_17"] = df["Time_End"].dt.hour > 17
df["birth_date"] = df["after_17"].map(lambda x: df["Time_End"].dt.date if x  else df["Time_End"].dt.date + pd.DateOffset(1))
```

It concatenated the output together and formed a row. How do I get it to work properly? I'm also open to other sort of solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `timedelta` method from the `datetime` library to add 7 hours to `Time_End` and then extract only the date component using `dt.date`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

data = {"Date": ["2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06"],  
        "Time_End":["2018-08-05 13:50:00", "2018-08-05 14:26:00", "2018-08-05 17:30:00", "2018-08-05 17:10:00", "2018-08-06 11:23:00"],
        "Reason":["blah1", "blah2", "blah3", "blah4", "blah5"]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).astype({'Time_End': 'datetime64'})

td = timedelta(hours=7)

df['Birth_Date'] = (df.Time_End + td).dt.date
```

**Output**

```
    Date        Time_End            Reason  Birth_Date
0   2018-08-05  2018-08-05 13:50:00 blah1   2018-08-05
1   2018-08-05  2018-08-05 14:26:00 blah2   2018-08-05
2   2018-08-05  2018-08-05 17:30:00 blah3   2018-08-06
3   2018-08-05  2018-08-05 17:10:00 blah4   2018-08-06
4   2018-08-06  2018-08-06 11:23:00 blah5   2018-08-06
```

Comment: Clever idea to use timedelta to push time forward. Besides, it's syntactically clean.

Answer (score 2):

Create a DateOffset of 1 day first:

```
date_offset = pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(n=1)
df['Birth_date'] = df.Time_End.apply(lambda x: x + date_offset if x.hour >= 17 else x).dt.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
data = {"Date": ["2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06"],  
        "Time_End":["2018-08-05 13:50:00", "2018-08-05 14:26:00", "2018-08-05 17:30:00", "2018-08-05 17:10:00", "2018-08-06 11:23:00"],
        "Reason":["blah1", "blah2", "blah3", "blah4", "blah5"]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert column into pandas datetime format
df['Time_End'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time_End"])

# Create a threshold value to compare
t = pd.to_datetime('17:00:00').time()

# Use datetime.timedelta to add a day for condition 
df['Birth_date'] = np.where(df['Time_End'].dt.time < t, df['Time_End'], df["Time_End"] + dt.timedelta(days=1) )
```

Output:

```
         Date            Time_End Reason           birthdate
0  2018-08-05 2018-08-05 13:50:00  blah1 2018-08-05 13:50:00
1  2018-08-05 2018-08-05 14:26:00  blah2 2018-08-05 14:26:00
2  2018-08-05 2018-08-05 17:30:00  blah3 2018-08-06 17:30:00
3  2018-08-05 2018-08-05 17:10:00  blah4 2018-08-06 17:10:00
4  2018-08-06 2018-08-06 11:23:00  blah5 2018-08-06 11:23:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the column first and then do the comparison later to add to the date :

```
df[['Birth-date', 'Time']] = df['Time_End'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```